# Unity C# First Person Script not Moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm pretty new to unity and I decided to make a simple first person game, however my script only allows the player to look around, not move. I have used AddForce, however I am not sure I have done it correctly.

```
public float walkSpeedForward = 5f;
public float walkSpeedStrafe = 4f;
public float walkSpeedBack = 3f;
public float sprintMultiplier = 2f;
public Camera cam;
public float sensitivityX = 0f;
public float sensitivityY = 0f;
public float minimumX = -360F;
public float maximumX = 360F;
public float minimumY = -60F;
public float maximumY = 60F;
public Rigidbody rb;
float rotationY = 0f;


// Use this for initialization
void Awake () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb.freezeRotation = true;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    float rotationX = cam.transform.localEulerAngles.y + Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
    rotationY += Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
    rotationY = Mathf.Clamp (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);
    cam.transform.localEulerAngles = (new Vector3(-rotationY, rotationX, 0f));

}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.AddForce (new Vector3 (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * walkSpeedStrafe * Time.deltaTime, 0, Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * walkSpeedForward * Time.deltaTime));
}
```

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html

Answer (score 1):

Do not use AddForce, it is physics pushing an object. Not actually Ideal to move a character.

You can learn how to properly make a script or even, use a ready script by clicking

Assets>Import Package> Characters. This package already have characters sounds and the Scripts that you're looking for. You can choose only the scripts if you want, but I suggest for you to import them all since you're trying to learn it. So you would know how to attach sounds, controls, models. As you learn form this package. FYI you don't need to download this, it is already on your computer.

Check this video [Click Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-a-ball/moving-the-player)

It will only take 12 min of your time.

Comment: I'm trying to learn the basics of scripting, and after following your suggestion I managed to go through the script. Whilst it was helpful, I am looking for a simpler solution that I could implement and use myself, rather than simply understand. The scripts covered a wide variety of topics and I would rather come back to them when I have a better understanding as they seem to be quite complex for a beginner to simply read and fully grasp. Is their an easier way for me to find out basics such as this, including something that would answer my particular problem in a not too complex way?

Comment: Unity3D already have a documentation that will 100% suit your needs. Almost identical to what you're doing. Do you want the Documentation or Do you want the 12 minute video?

Comment: Click the Link on my Answer